# Simple dom parser results in multiple pages

Tags: php, parsing, dom

I have parsed a page to get the titles, and sometimes the parsed titles are more than 11. My designed template contain max 11 titles. My question is how to replicate the template () for the rest of the titles (from 12 -> n). I have to replicate the template somehow for the rest of results, but I don't know exactly how. 
Bellow is my template, witch is displaying all the results.

```
<?php 
    include('parse/simple_html_dom.php'); 
    $url = 'link-to-url';
    $html = file_get_html($url);
    $headlines = array();
    $i = 0;
?>
<div class="pf w0 h0">
    <div class="w0 h0">
        <div class="header-pagina">
            <svg role="img"  class="header37"><use xlink:href="#header-hp"></use></svg>
        </div>

        <div class="page-wrapper">
            <?php 
           foreach($html->find('.cmsmasters_row[1] .cmsmasters_toggle_title') as $title) {
                    $i++;
                        echo '<div class="agenda-curs">';
                        echo '<div class="agenda-tab"><span class="modul-tab-text color1" contenteditable="true">Modulul '.$i.'</span></div>';   
                        echo '<div class="agenda-text" contenteditable="true">'.$headlines[] = $title->plaintext.'</div >';

                        echo '</div>';
            }
            $head = implode("", $headlines);
            ?>
        </div>
        <svg role="img" class="footer35"><use xlink:href="#footer35"></use></svg>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Fyi, `implode()` doesn't need glue, if you want to join with an empty string.  It hink your question may be Too Broad.  Where do you want to write the pagination button/links on your page?  Have you searched for pagination pages on Stackoverflow?

Comment: No, I do not want a pagination,  I want to replicate the template for the 12-22 parsed results, that means the all content of "<div class="pf w0 h0">..."

Comment: So you want to `break` your foreach() after 10 iterations and write a while() loop that fetches all of the results? I recommend doing all of your processing before you start printing to screen.  You can just batch the imploded `$head`s right?

Comment: I do not have a clue how to do that

Comment: Need some help with this, anyone, please ?

Comment: Going to bed now.  If you don't have an answer when I check in the morning, I'll give it a crack.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190142/discussion-between-vectorial-graphics-and-mickmackusa).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you are using `$head = implode("", $headlines);` for in your script but you will be able to glean the data that you want from `$headlines` or `headline_batch` below.

Separating your processing from your printing will make your code easier to read and maintain.  I could write the script to use less loops, but I am favoring readability over efficiency.

```
<?php 
include('parse/simple_html_dom.php'); 
$url = 'link-to-url';
$html = file_get_html($url);
$headlines = array();
$counter = 0;
foreach($html->find('.cmsmasters_row[1] .cmsmasters_toggle_title') as $title) {
    $headlines[++$counter] = $title->plaintext;
}

// no more processing, just printing
foreach (array_chunk($headlines, 10, true) as $headline_batch) {
    ?>
    <div class="pf w0 h0">
        <div class="w0 h0">
            <div class="header-pagina">
                <svg role="img"  class="header37"><use xlink:href="#header-hp"></use></svg>
            </div>
            <?php

            foreach ($headline_batch as $counter => $title) {
                echo '<div class="agenda-curs">
                          <div class="agenda-tab"><span class="modul-tab-text color1" contenteditable="true">Modulul ' . $counter . '</span></div>
                          <div class="agenda-text" contenteditable="true">' . $title . '</div >
                      </div>';
            }

            ?>
            </div>
            <svg role="img" class="footer35"><use xlink:href="#footer35"></use></svg>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Using `array_chunk($headlines, 10, true)` will spare you having to use a modulus condition in your loop to check if a new group should be started.  The `true` parameter retains the `$counter` values after splitting into groups.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was exactly what I need it..
Now have a similar issue, do you have a minute extra to look over it ?

Comment: Sorry to hear that, I hope is not something serious.
I have pasted the piece of code, the link is: https://3v4l.org/Cr6Ie
My issue is that I have to parse 2 variables, and put them in same template. And one of the variables is repeating... How I combine those 2 foreach in a single one ?

Comment: Let me ask... do you actually need to push new elements into `head` and `headlines`? I don't see your script using those arrays after they are generated.

Comment: Again, you should extract all of your values and prepare them (use strpos&substr instead of strstr&substr) and store them in pairs, then output the paired data with your static html.  It'll be cleaner that way.

Comment: I don't know exactly how to re-arrange the code, what you did before it was amazing, I`m not sure I can reach to these solutions.

Comment: I must not continue with too many comments, I will need to see a few sections (not necessarily the whole file) of the html file being parsed to offer the best possible approach for your task.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190183/discussion-between-vectorial-graphics-and-mickmackusa).

Comment: Sorry, I've been swamped with work.  I'll try to find time to circle back to this extra question in the near future.